# UIPickerView calls didSelectRow: with the wrong row when animated

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` which is being animated when the user is done with it. The animation is as follows:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.pickerView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

When this animation runs, the `UIPickerView` calls its delegate method `didSelectRow: inComponent:` with a row number that is 4 higher than the actual selected row. That should not happen.

When I comment out the alpha animation and leave the rest in tact, the delegate method is called with the correct row number.

What on earth is going on here?

Comment: How do you determine the user is done with the PickerView? What exactly triggers the animation?

Comment: @Fourth a `UIButton` to close the pickerview calls an `IBAction`. Inside the IBAction is the above code.